# dialog box controls - detect changes

Tags: c++, winapi, modal-dialog

I want to detect when any control on a dialog box is changed by user action.  For example, when data is entered in a text box, a date is entered in a date-time picker, a check box is checked or unchecked, etc.  Up to now I have ignored such notifications and simply retrieved the state of the controls when the user pushes some button but now I want to know a change has taken place (I want to enable the Apply button on a property sheet).  I don't really care what change has taken place, all I want to know is that something has changed.  By change I do NOT mean a change in focus but some actual action by the user to change a control.

I use plain old c++, no MFC or anything fancy.

How do I go about this?

Comment: Are you using Win32 API for the GUI if it's not MFC?

Comment: @jaywalker: Yes, a Win32 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test whether a checkbox has been checked with the [BN_CLICKED](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761825%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) notification code which you'd get through WM_COMMAND.

```
switch( uMsg ) {
  ...
  case WM_COMMAND: {
    switch( HIWORD( wParam ) ) {
    case BN_CLICKED: {
      if( Button_GetCheck( lParam ) == BST_CHECKED ) {
        ...
      }

      break;
    }
    default:
      return false;
    }
    break;
  }
  default:
    return false;
}

return true;
```

That is an example of how your DialogProc might be set up. You can switch on lParam or `LOWORD( wParam )` to identify which button.

Comment: so i must do something specific to each type of control?  any idea how to detect that a text box has changed?

Comment: You can check for EN_CHANGE for edit controls. If you don't care about which button or which text box was clicked/edited just get rid of the if() part. Different types of controls tend to have different notification codes for changes so all you need to do is wait for any of those in your WndProc

Comment: My little demo has two tabs in its Property Sheet.  In processing the WM_COMMAND notification, I added the following   if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE)
   {
    SendMessage (GetParent(hDlg), PSM_CHANGED, 0, 0);
    return FALSE;
   }  so if I alter the edit box in the first tab that comes up, the APPLY button gets enabled but if I first switch to the second tab and then back to the first tab b4 I alter the edit box, the APPLY button does not get enabled.  Any idea what might be happening?  As far as I can tell, hDlg is the same after I switch tabs A->B->A.

Comment: I modified the SendMessage to read as follows and all is well.      SendMessage (GetParent(hDlg), PSM_CHANGED, (WPARAM) hDlg, 0);
The documentation for Property Sheets is sure terrible!